# ubuntu-vm-builder and first-login interactive script

Tags: login, scripts, keyboard-layout, vmbuilder

I'm using ubuntu-vm-builder to create disk image on-the-fly. I want to use a script to change user keyboard on first login with --firstlogin argument with the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Running reconfigure of console-data to change keyboard layout
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

When I attempt my first login, ubuntu ask me for my root password without displaying ncurses to change keyboard layout and return directly to the bash prompt.

Any idea of how can I have interactive keyboard layout change display ?

Regards,
Thibault.

Comment: This may be due to a [long-standing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/vmbuilder/+bug/378862) where the script is never run.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using sudo, you will need the root password. What's the problem with that?